# Mediawiki engine only works on Lan, works intermittently externally

Tags: php, mediawiki, ubuntu-11.04

I have recently installed a LAMP server running ubuntu server 11.04. I am trying to run a private mediawiki engine online, version 1.17.0. For some odd reason it works perfectly on the LAN only, when I use an external network, it would continue load forever and proceed to being timed out. Other folders I have seemed to be doing fine externally so I believe my network configuration should be ok. Sometimes when I do get lucky (like 10% of the time), it will load normally for a few pages and resume once again to hanging. If I stop the page load it would appear but the skin would be missing.

I used firebug and found that 2 processes with something like load.php/debug=false....style:skin=vector that is hanging while all the other files load fine. If I stopped all the extensions, killed both common.js and common.css, and prevent the use of javascript on the site, it would work fine (relatively speaking, it would load everything quickly). I think it is a javascript problem but I am not sure where to look for an error log for java.

When checking the firefox error console I also noted the same error location had a "message: expected '}'". However, when running in the LAN it has the same message but it still works fine. I tried looking through all possible resources but to no avail.

Comment: That's curious... the mention of load.php suggests it might be a problem in [ResourceLoader](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader), but I have no idea why it should break only on remote connections.  (Then again, it might just be that the hangs occur randomly on all requests, so that on those occasions where you manage to fetch the page itself, the next request -- which will most likely be to load.php -- is likely to be the one to hang.)

Comment: Anyway, some things to try: a) Turn on [debug logging](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug); it'll spew a lot of noise into the log, but there might be something useful in there. b) Try appending `debug=true` to the URL to enable [RL debug mode](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Developing_with_ResourceLoader); if that fixes it, the problem is definitely in ResourceLoader.

Comment: Actually I've tried the debug=true on my URL but no luck, if anything made it worse for some odd reason. But I'll try to turn on all debugging elements in my localsettings.php and I'll post up the results.

I'm kind of sure its not a random thing for all requests because prior to making it "live" over the net, I did all my testing on the LAN for 3 months and everything was smooth. I can only remember once in 3 months that it lagged for 2 seconds after i clicked a link. But as soon as I started to broadcast it to the web (I have a router so I port forwarded and stopped firewals), this happen.

Comment: Ok so after a few days fiddling with the debug functions, I still don't really have an answer. However I did see an option on the mediawiki debug page suggesting to enable profiling but I'm not sure how to start it, can anyone help?

Comment: Actually I justed noticed a section on the debug that says "Class SkinVector not found; skipped loading" when I tried to load it on my lan. Maybe it skips loading when its on the LAN but it continues to try externally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution to this problem: it was a networking issue afterall. I checked all the logs and could not find anything. But found that the problem was that the ubuntu was running under a dchp setting so I changed it into a static ip mode and now it works perfectly. Althought I don't understand why it would make a difference between broadcasting via LAN only vs. external, it works perfectly now. Thanks to anyone who tried